# How to fix "Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, turbolinks

I can't push my code to heroku but it works in local.
When i make `rake assets:precompile` in terminal, i've this answer:
`rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'turbolinks' with type 'application/javascript'` I don't want use Sprockets anymore

I tryed this: https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/rails-custom-elements-with-turbolinks-webpack/

but when i make :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Turbolinks::Redirection
  # ...
end
```

I've this error `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Turbolinks` from error consol

My application.js from app/javascript/packs/

```
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks'
Turbolinks.start()

import '../css/application.scss'
import 'bootstrap'
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "**********",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "3.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.6",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:******/*************.git",
  "author": "******* <******@email.com>",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test]
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'turbolinks', require: false
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

My webpacker.yml from app/config/webpack/

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

My application.html.erb from app/views/layouts

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval': false, defer: true %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', defer: true %>
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the problem lied in application.js. After creating a brand new Ruby on Rails app my application.js header looked like this:

**Before**

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

The *//=require turbolinks* seemed to be causing the problem because I never installed turbolinks or anything of the sort. Removing this line fixed the issue for me:

**After**

```
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I just created a new project without the --skip-sprockets option and now its works with webpack